# iPhone - developing a game using iOS Game Kit

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I am about to add Game Kit functionality to a game I am developing. The game type is more like a head to head game, instead of turn based. What I mean is this: I need other players to see live what the playing user is doing, like a car racing application, for example, where all players compete against each other live and they all see what is going on live.

Can you guys point me to an example of how to do that? A sample code, tutorial, anything.

I have google around but just found vague and superficial approaches.

At this time I just need to know about implementing online games using Game Center, not local network (bluetooth/wifi).

Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's the part Game Center doesn't give you. You have to make your own communication schemes and protocols. Native Game Kit communication protocols are just poor.

Don't get me wrong, it's a great framework to create and find matches but you are on your own on the communication.

You should check the Game Kit reference and the Protocol References section.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html

Comment: That explains why I have not found anything relevant on google... but tell me one thing: once you have multiple users are connected on game center playing that match, on different parts of the world, it is possible to pass data between them, right?

Comment: Absolutely. Here are some examples on apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKRocket/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009747 and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008918

Comment: ahhhh... thanks. It is good to know that this works for people not on the local network too! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In game kit programming guide, the documentation says in the section [Using Matches to Implement Your Network Game](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchesandVoice/MatchesandVoice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH10-SW9)

> A match is group of players whose devices are connected to each other over a network by Game Center. Matches allow data and voice to be transmitted to other participants in the match. Game Center manages the difficult effort of finding other players and **establishing the network between them**. This frees you to work on designing your network game.